# Analytic solution for $A\cos(x+\theta)+B\cos{2x}+Cx+D=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is there any analytic solution for $f(x)=0$?

Where $f(x)=A\cos(x+\theta)+B\cos{2x}+Cx+D$

and

$x \in \left[ 0,\frac{\pi}{2} \right]$
,
$\theta \in \left[ 0,\pi \right]$

and $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: You could use $\cos(x+\theta)=\cos x\cos\theta-\sin x\sin\theta$, and $\sin x=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$, and $\cos2x=2\cos^x-1$ to get  everything in terms of $\cos x$, but the algebra after that might be awkward.

Comment: The problem is the $C x$ term. Do not expect any closed form solution.

Comment: I was sure it was $\cos x$, not $Cx$, but I must have misread the question. @Claude is right, approximate solutions via numerical methods are to be expected.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. I was sure about it ! Cheers :-)